# Java:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/validation/ConstraintDescriptor

Tags: java, gwt

[image]I am facing this error while running my Java/ GWT application

Any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - find the JAR that has that .class file in it and add it to your CLASSPATH.  Java 101.

Looks like it's part of the Jackson JSON library:

http://jackson.codehaus.org/javadoc/bean-validation-api/1.0/javax/validation/ConstraintDescriptor.html

Download it and put it in your CLASSPATH.  Done!

Comment: Also, if you are trying to run it client-side, make sure it can be properly translated to JS by GWT's compiler.

Comment: I already have json-lib in my classpath , and the link you provided to download , couldnt find any lib there

Comment: Right, it was the javadocs for that class.  The link just shows who owns it.  And if you have it in your CLASSPATH, then why are you getting that error?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you think you have it in your CLASSPATH, but the error is evidence that you are incorrect.  Check your assumptions.  If you assume you're wrong, you'll make progress towards getting it corrected much faster.

Comment: i've attached the screenshot, please suggest whats causing the error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7109/discussion-between-junaidp-and-duffymo)

Answer (score 0):

find out if the library you're trying to use is compatible with GWT and find a compatible one if it's not!